# Smart way to search a word in a list

Tags: python, string, list

I want to make a python program that is able to search through a list of words in a smart way.

Let's say that I have a list like this:

```
ex_list=["Red Apples", "Green Apples", "Bananas", "Yoghurt", "ApplePie", "Milk", "Pineapple"]
```

And the word I want to search is:

```
search_word = "Apple"
```

The way I want the program to work is so that it returns "Red Apples", "Green Apples", "ApplePie" and "Pineapple". (Since, they all contain apple)

How do I achieve that?

I basically want it to return everything that has "a", then "p", then "p", "l", and "e". I don´t care what is in front(like greenapple) or in the back(like applePie).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One-liner with filter:

```
list(filter(lambda x: search_word.lower() in x.lower(), ex_list))
```

Or with list comprehension:

```
[x for x in ex_list if search_word.lower() in x.lower()]
```

Just filter your list by condition that `ex_list` element contains `search_word` (case insensitive).

Result:

```
['Red Apples', 'Green Apples', 'ApplePie', 'Pineapple']
```